# Accessing calendar event data in FullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

I'm trying to use FullCalendar to render the events from a Google calendar on a webpage. I want the starting date/time, description, and place. Future events in one div and past events in another.

Right now I have FullCalendar working to its basic functionality: a complete calendar on my page that displays my gcal events.

So my question is: how can I access the data and render it as text on my page? There is a block of code in the gcal.js file that looks like this

```
events.push({
   id: entry['gCal$uid']['value'],
   title: entry['title']['$t'],
   url: url,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay,
   location: entry['gd$where'][0]['valueString'],
   description: entry['content']['$t']
  });
});
```

how would I go about accessing this events array?

Hope this question isn't too vague, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [clientEvents](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/clientEvents/)

You can also use a function, like:

```
mycal.fullCalendar('clientEvents', function(ev) {
 // ev is Event object...
});
```